# Watching for div width changes in vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an nuxt app where I have two sidebars, one on the left and one on the right.

Both are fixed and body has padding from right and left.

In the middle I have `<nuxt/>` that loads pages.

Left sidebar can be minimized to `60px` so I cannot use media queries for this and I need to watch for `<nuxt/> width` changes, in case that width is `< 500px` I would add some other classes. Something like media queries for element instead of viewport.

Is there a way to do this without additional javascript libraries, plugins etc..?

Comment: What about [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)? To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API), "[t]he Resize Observer API provides a performant mechanism by which code can monitor an element for changes to its size, with notifications being delivered to the observer each time the size changes."

Answer (score 0):

**updated with two slider example:**

A way to achieve the desired behavior will be to bind a dynamic `width` to your sliders and watch that `width` prop then bind the classes using the element `ref` upon changes :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      silderWidth: {
        first: '100',
        second: '100'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    first() {
      return this.silderWidth.first
    },
    second() {
      return this.silderWidth.second
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleWidth(ele) {
      this.silderWidth[ele] === '100' ?
        this.silderWidth[ele] = "200" :
        this.silderWidth[ele] = "100"
    }
  },
  watch: {
    first() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.silderWidth.first === '200' ?
          this.$refs.silderWidth1.classList.add('background') :
          this.$refs.silderWidth1.classList.remove('background')
      })
    },
    second() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.silderWidth.second === '200' ?
          this.$refs.silderWidth2.classList.add('background') :
          this.$refs.silderWidth2.classList.remove('background')
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.silder {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.silder--1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.silder--2 {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.background {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="silder silder--1" ref="silderWidth1" :style="{ width : first + 'px'}" @click="toggleWidth('first')"></div>
  <div class="silder silder--2" ref="silderWidth2" :style="{ width : second + 'px'}" @click="toggleWidth('second')"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good but not enough, can I listen somehow to any type of width change and then assign it to data value? On click I am not achieving much

Comment: @Learner sadly i was looking for something that can do that such as an event listener to detect element resize changes but couldn't find anything helpfull

Comment: Seems like you are right, I've found this and it is additional package, but I ll give it a try:

https://itnext.io/making-adaptive-vue-components-with-resizeobserver-123b5ebb20ae

Comment: I see your example with two sliders and I could listen for sidebars changes and sub it from total width to get inner. But in my case I would need to check if left one is minimized or not and for right one is it hidden or not. If it is hidden then there is no padding from right and if left one is minimized its only 60px and then I would need to get body width or window width - 60px as that one in middle. But  it seems like a lot of work for something like that, what if I need same thing within middle one? It gets tricky then

Comment: you got the idea .. true its a lot of work but i am not sure if there is a better way to achieve this ....you can use extra conditions for the others.

Comment: this https://github.com/Kelin2025/vue-responsive-components works exactly as we need. I suck at programming so I the hell dont know how it works but it does :D

Comment: @Learner i'm glad you found it and share it with us :)

Comment: Dadboz I got problem with this :D Out of nowhere.... It was working well until I tried to add vue multiselect... After that it kept showing some "Unexpected identifier" error without any explanation... Only for this package on import....

Comment: And seems like adding it to plugin and using mode: 'client' fixed

Answer (score -3):

Hope this helps:

```
window.onresize = () => {
    let width = document.querySelector('nuxt').offsetWidth;
    console.log(width);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - [tour], please check [answer]. You have to provide an explanation about how this code solves the problem of the OP "orginal poster".